# How to dispose of Autofac container used with Caliburn Micro

Tags: dispose, autofac, caliburn.micro

I have a Winforms menu item that brings up a WPF form when clicked. The WPF form uses Caliburn Micro, bootstrapped with Autofac.

It just occurred to me recently that the Caliburn bootstrapper resolves dependencies from the root Autofac container. Therefore, these dependencies (e.g. a view model with 1000s of data items to be bound to a grid) never gets disposed.

I'd like to use an Autofac lifetimescope container to manage the dispose, however, I'm not sure how to do this with Caliburn. Initially, I thought to instantiate one Caliburn bootstrapper (with its own Autofac lifetimescope container) for each WPF form that's opened. Then, when the form is disposed, the bootstrapper can be disposed (and the lifetimescope container with it).

However, from looking at the Caliburn source, it seems that only one bootstrapper should be created for the whole application. This is because instantiating the bootstrapper seems to assign static fields to do with UI marshalling (and perhaps other things I may not have seen).

Does anyone have any recommendations/suggestions on how I can dispose of dependencies when the WPF form is closed?

Comment: I asked a similar question in relation to Castle. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9583760/246811. As yet there has not been a workable answer.

Comment: I did see your post before asking my question. Like you, I'm looking for a way to do this without polluting the VM. Further, I'm not sure why there isn't more information about this online already - it seems like a fairly big problem with the use of Caliburn (at least with Autofac and Castle, which are 2 popular DI frameworks).

Comment: Agree. Pollution of VM with lifecycle concerns was not something I can live with.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using the following to release view models resolved from Castle (until something better comes along!). I'm not familiar with AutoFac, but maybe this approach could be of use. In your bootstrapper:

```
protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
{
        // Get the instance from the container
        ...

        // If it's activatable, monitor it so we can release when closed.
        IDeactivate activatable = result as IDeactivate;
        if (activatable != null)
        {
            activatable.Deactivated += activatable_Deactivated;
        }
        return result;
}

    void activatable_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.WasClosed)
        {
            ((IDeactivate)sender).Deactivated -= activatable_Deactivated;
            container.Release(sender); // or whatever AutoFac equivalent is...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Unfortunately, I'm not sure that this will work for Autofac. Autofac's lifecycle management approach centers around creating child containers that can be disposed when a unit of work is done. This means that the bootstrapper would need to know which child container to resolve dependencies from, and which child container to dispose. I haven't yet checked to see if Autofac supports a container.Release style method from the root container.