# Windsor is not releasing my transient components, even after I call Release

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container, castle

I fear that I may be missing something basic/fundamental.  I'm trying to use Castle.Windsor in a WinForms/WPF application, but I'm running into issues with the Lifestyle of my components.

I have a TypedFactory called ViewFactory that I use to resolve my views.  Each view needs a ViewModel, so I have interfaces for them, and have components registered so that Windsor will take care of injecting them, for me.  I've been using the "Transient" Lifestyle for everything, because I can't find anything that matches better.  I then try to "Release" them when I'm done, but they stick around forever.  This is causing every-increasing memory consumption.

My registrations:

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>

container.Register(
    Component.For<IDemoViewModel>()
        .ImplementedBy<DemoViewModel>()
        .LifestyleTransient(),
    Component.For<IDemoView>()
        .ImplementedBy<DemoView>()
        .LifestyleTransient(),
    Component.For<IViewFactory>()
        .AsFactory()
    );
```

My IViewFactory is simple:

```
public interface IViewFactory
{
    T Create<T>()
    void Release(IView view)
}
```

I am using my ViewFactory to create an instance of my view:

```
ViewFactory.Create<DemoView>();
```

In the constructor of my DemoView, I have a parameter for my IViewModel interface, so that Castle.Windsor can resolve and inject an instance, for me.  When the form is closed, I explicitly try to release the View.

```
public class DemoView
{
    public IViewFactory ViewFactory { get; set; }

    private IDemoViewModel _viewModel;

    public DemoView(IDemoViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        DataContext = _viewModel;

        this.Closed += new FormClosedEventHandler(HandleViewClosing);
    }

    private void HandleViewClosing(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewFactory.Release(this);
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any light that can be shed on how to properly handle Views/ViewModels with Castle.Windsor.  When the View is closed, I need the View, and any dependencies that were created for it, destroyed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that Windsor is keeping a reference to your components ? You can check this in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Marwijn.  I checked the debugger per [link](http://goo.gl/9FAaw), and I do see Castle.Windsor holding a reference to my components under the "Objects tracked by release policy" collection.  I set breakpoints, and observed the following: prior to resolving view (no view/model in collection), after resolving view (view/model in collection), and after calling ViewFactory.Release (view/view model still in collection).  I also set a breakpoint in the Finalize method and it was not called until I disposed of the container.  What can prevent .Release from doing it's job?

Comment: Usually the typed factory that releases the component is the same that created it. Looking at your code sample is not seems to happening so...Injecting a factory into the object created by the same factory smells. You may consider a "Composition Root" approach to create your views or a main component that act as Composition root having a dependency on a factory that create & release views

Comment: I believe I do have a Composition Root, already.  That is where I create the container, register my installers, resolve my main view, and ultimately dispose of the container, right?  My issue is that my "main" view has a ViewFactory injected, and the views that it creates are hanging around until the container is disposed of.  I've searched Google for hours and I cant find a working example of how to use Castle.Windsor with WPF that doesn't exhibit the same memory leak that I have.  Is anyone aware of an example that addresses this -- even if it means changing my approach.  Thanks.

Comment: I was also thinking that a different container was used for releasing, but looking at the registration code, the factory seems to be a singleton. So that should not pose a problem. May be a bit beside the point here, but why not use a tool like Caliburn.Micro for coupling views and viewmodels ?

Comment: Agree with Cristiano. As an aside, generally the component that's responsible for Resolve should also be responsible for Release. Embedding knowledge of the factory in the component defeats the IOC objective of loose coupling. On the Caliburn Micro suggestion, it is a nice framework for WPF but unfortunately it lacks hooks for calling Release().

Comment: I'm confused why you are saying that using the Factory in the component defeats the objective of IOC; my understanding from [link](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx) and [link](http://kozmic.net/2009/12/23/castle-typed-factory-facility-reborn/) is that they specifically address this concern.  If you have an alternative solution, I'm all ears.  At this point, I'd really like to see a working example of an implementation that allows separation of View and ViewModel and handles dependency injection without leaking memory.

Comment: The note about embedding of Factory into your view is a sidebar - it's not causing the problem you've raised. It's a smell because you've got container details leaking into your component: DemoView should not know anything about IViewFactory or any other implementation details of how it gets created/destroyed. An alternative approach would be to add a handler to Closed, after you've called Create(). That way the Release call exists in only one place, not in every view within your project. Does that make sense?

Comment: Finalize won't get called until GC takes place and that will not occur if you've got other things causing memory leaks. Can you implement IDisposable() on one of your views and put a breakpoint in there to see if it's getting called when you call Release()? If so, you may be able to debug and figure out why Windsor is continuing to track the view.

Comment: I implemented IDisposable and set a breakpoint in the Dispose() method.  It is not called after I Invoke Release().  My breakpoint does not get hit until I close the application and destroy the container.

Comment: @Phil Why do you state that it lacks hooks for calling release. Are you using it view first ? I always used it viewmodel first and I've no problems with calling release.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583760/disposing-of-viewmodels-in-caliburn-micro-and-castle-windsor

Comment: @p07r0457, that's extremely wierd. Calling Release on a transient component should immediately result in the object being disposed. I'm at a loss.